# node PostgresSQL

Tags: sql, node.js, reactjs, postgresql, express

Im trying to query a postgres db but my query isnt returning anything useful. It works when I dont use parameter sub i.e. `const sql = "SELECT acronym, definition FROM terms WHERE acronym='Thing'"` but im not to sure how this should be done. I tried the obvious way but no bueno. I think it might be because postgres sql "does not support parameters for identifies" whatever that means  Anyone know why my query isnt working?

```
app.get("/terms", async (req, res) => {
  let values = req.query.term;
  const sql = "SELECT acronym,definition FROM terms WHERE acronym($1)";
  
  const terms = await pgClient.query(sql, values);

  res.send(terms);
  pgClient.end();
});
```

## When Working

```
{data: {…}, status: 200, statusText: 'OK', headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
config: {transformRequest: {…}, transformResponse: {…}, timeout: 0, xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN', adapter: ƒ, …}
data: {command: 'SELECT', rowCount: 46, oid: null, rows: Array(46), fields: Array(2), …}
headers: {access-control-allow-origin: '*', connection: 'keep-alive', content-length: '10023', content-type: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', date: 'Sat, 15 Jan 2022 10:41:45 GMT', …}
request: XMLHttpRequest {readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, onreadystatechange: ƒ, …}
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
[[Prototype]]: Object...
```

## Not Working

```
xhr.js:178 POST http://localhost:8080/api/values 502 (Bad Gateway)
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:178
xhrAdapter @ xhr.js:12
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:59
Promise.then (async)
request @ Axios.js:51
Axios.<computed> @ Axios.js:71
wrap @ bind.js:9
...
xhr.js:178 GET http://localhost:8080/api/terms/all?term=Word 502 (Bad Gateway)

dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:4168
createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 502
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:77)
```

Answer (score 0):

Two remarks about your code:

- `values` must be an array with one entry per parameter
- The parameters appear in the SQL query as `$1, $2, ...` (or, depending on the database, as `?`) without any change in the other syntax. Strings need not be quoted again.

```js
let values = [req.query.term]; // an array containing the string
const sql = "SELECT acronym,definition FROM terms WHERE acronym=$1";
const terms = await pgClient.query(sql, values);
```

Comment: thxs my guy sometimes when your doing this stuff at 2am you miss the small things